# Modifying Powershell Script to amend 'Last Modified Date' of sub-folders within selected directory

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created the below script, which has been tested and working successfully, to amend the 'Last Modified Date' of all files contained in the selected folder.

```
$a = Get-Date "22/11/2012 10:00 AM"

$b = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyFiles"

foreach ($i in $b)
{
    $i.LastWriteTime = $a
    $a = $a.AddMinutes(1)    
}

$b
```

I am just looking for some help amending this script to include all subfolders/file within the selected folder, as I am currently having to amend this manually to change the date within the sub-folders of "C:\MyFiles".. for e.g. "C:\MyFiles\A", "C:\MyFiles\B".. etc.

In addition.. I was also wondering how I can remove the line "$a = Get-Date "22/11/2012 10:00 AM" so that it automatically sets the date to todays, and I do not have to enter a date manually.

Comment: I am very new to Powershell but.. I have now amended this to get the current date/time, but I assume that $a.AddMinutes can now be removed/amended as this would not be required?

$a = Get-Date

$b = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyFiles"

foreach ($i in $b)
{
    $i.LastWriteTime = $a
    $a = $a.AddMinutes(0)    
}

$b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
    $a = get-date
    $b = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyFiles" -recurse | ? { !$_.psiscontainer }
    foreach ($i in $b)
    {
        $i.LastWriteTime = $a 
        $a = $a.AddMinutes(1)    
    }

    $b
```

or if you don't need to add a minute after each file:

```
     $dir = read-host "Insert path"
     $b = Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | ? { !$_.psiscontainer }
    foreach ($i in $b)
    {
        $i.LastWriteTime = get-date               
    }

    $b
```

Comment: Perfect!.. this now amends the time/date within all sub-folders!. I don't suppose you would mind helping with above comment, is the $a.AddMinutes needed? as I don't really need to have the date showing as +1 minute of that of its previous file, these can all just be set to todays date/time.

Comment: Cheer!.. this is going a bit further than what I need, but how would I change the selected directory "C:\MyFiles" into actual input, therefore allowing me to just enter the directory I require before hand, as that is the only bit now I am having to amend manually within the script (.ps1) itself.

Comment: @welowkey Edited my aswer. Try it